# Color Variables with bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Getting around to using sass in my latest rails project, specifically the bootstrap-sass gem to get all of twitter bootstrappy goodness.

Is it possible to reference the variables already defined?  The vendor `/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss` file contains declarations for colors.

```
$blue: #049cdb !default;
$blueDark: #0064cd !default;
$green: #46a546 !default;
$red: #9d261d !default;
```

Do I need to redefine these in the top of my base `application.css.scss` file or can I import/reference the variables file? I've tried a couple of approaches like this:

```
$bodyBackground: $black;
@import 'bootstrap'
```

But that errors out with undefined variable `$black`.

Answer (score 3):

First, define the variable `$black`:

```
$black: #000;
$bodyBackground: $black;
@import "bootstrap";
```

or change it to:

```
$bodyBackground: #000;
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the below two lines from `application.scss` file:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```